# Runtime Error 1004 on the second macro execution

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

It Used to work well before protecting the sheet

I searched for a similar problem here in SO but didn't solve my problem. I don't know if it is specific to my code.

I have a sheet protected and all cells locked except for one Range which I call R. I copy the content From R to R2 but I need to unprotect the sheet first. Then I copy all from R to R2 then Lock and protect the sheet again. As I said the second time I run the macro, it throws a 1004 error and can't figure out why. The code worked well until I protected the sheet all the time. Here is the code:

It throws the error in the line where it says

```
.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
```

> *Runtime Error 1004 on the PasteSpecial method of the .Range Class*

```
Sub CopyPapers(ByRef R As Range, R2 As Range)
    With R2
        R.Copy
        Hoja1.Unprotect
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
        .Locked = True
        Hoja1.Protect
    End With

    R.Cells(2, 1).Activate
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

*R* and *R2* are ranges of cells.
Whenever I update the content in *R*, that content and formats are copied over to *R2*.
For that I use the **Worksheet_Change()** event and I check wheter only the range (*R*) is modified using **Intersect()** method.

Edit: I ignore why but moving **R.Copy** instruction under **Hoja1.Unprotect** seems to solve the problem.
If anyone can explain why that it I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Is that the entire code? What is R and R2?

Comment: @Davesexcel I updated the question. I found the fix, but I still don't know why a simple 2 line swap solved the problem...

Comment: Not a scientific explanation by any means, but I believe sometimes the clipboard can get cleared if there are intermediate actions taken between the copy and paste. Copying and then pasting immediately is preferable if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the calling of `Unprotect` method cancels the `Copy` command previuosly issued, so the subsequent `PasteSpecial` fails

BTW the correct statements sequence should be

```
Sub CopyPapers(ByRef R As Range, R2 As Range)
    Hoja1.Unprotect
    R.Copy
    With R2
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        .Locked = True
    End With
    Hoja1.Protect

    R.Cells(2, 1).Activate
End Sub
```

in order to

- `Unprotect` first
- populate `With .. End With` block with statements that belong to it only
- run `Application.CutCopyMode = False` as soon as possible

And yet there should be some changes to do in order to check that `R` and `R2` ranges do belong to `Hoja1` sheet

for instance you could use `R.Parent.Unprotect` and `R.Parent.Protect` to ensure you're acting on the sheet to which `R` belongs. And still assuming R2 belongs to it too...

Finally, be sure your `Worksheet_Change()` event handler doesn't call itself recursively, disabling `Application.EnableEvents` before the call to `CopyPapers()` and enabling it before exiting

Comment: Thanks a lot!
I did disable the events and enabled them as the last step in the event handler.
I'm not sure how to do the thing you say about checking if Ranges belong to Hoja1 sheet.
When I pass R and R2 variables, I predefine them before using Hoja1.Range() as well. I'm not sure if that would be valid, since I know Hoja1 is the sheet that I will be using always in this case.
Again, thanks a lot.

Comment: You are welcome. To check if a `R` range belongs to a `sht` sheet you could use `R.Parent = sht.Name`. Or you could use `R.Parent` to reference the sheet `R` belongs to. If you are already sure that both `R` and `R2` do belong to `Hoja1` you can go on as you're doing, but keeping in mind that is not a safe coding approach

Comment: I'll try doing that then. Thanks